# SSL handshake aborted Unity Facebook SDK

Tags: android, ios, facebook, ssl

I'm having following exception being thrown while using Facebook SDK for Unity:

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x5072f090: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0x4fd4b87e:0x00000000)

I've been hearing thing about POODLE and how SSLv3 is probably disabled server side. The weird thing is that this is only happening on some mobile devices (both iOS and android), and only when connected via 3G/4G cellular data. On Wifi it is working perfectly. Logging in works but certain other requests don't work. I'm at a loss.

I'm using the latest Unity version 4.5.5, and the Facebook SDK is 5.1. I realize 6 is already out but it auto connects to API v2 which I don't want at this time. I just want to fix this issue for existing v1 FB API ASAP before making long term changes to v2 API.

Any thoughts?

Comment: SSLv3 is disabled on the server. So you need to make the phones be able to use TLS.

Comment: But that is a phone setting or a setting I need to make in code? Because since it's an SDK provided, I don't have access to it.

Comment: Hello Sascha, I have the same problem, did you managed to fix the issue, and if yes can u post the resolution here, thx

Comment: Hi Tazz, 
Unfortunately I have not found a solution to this. I wish I could help you out but I can't. I do believe that the newer version of Facebook SDK for Unity have resolved this, but I never tested. I hope you can manage to get around it.